# How do I Start xfce4 desktop

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, xfce, xfce4-terminal

I have an ssh connection onto my pc , what command could I run on boot , to log into / create and log into an xfce4 session for my user account on my computer  I.e how do I unlock it on startup via ssh?

Comment: Perhaps you want to use VNC.

Answer (score 1):

SSH (Secure Shell) is a terminal-based service, so short answer for you is: **You can not sign in to your desktop environment (XFCE in this case) by using SSH.** If you want to connect to your target machine and use a desktop environment, you have to use services like VNC or it's alternatives.

Also, SSH is a service managed by **Service Managers** like `systemd`, so you have no access to it before your OS in Running state. If it is your own PC and you connecting to it by keyboard, this doesn't mean you are using SSH at all. Most of the client distributions come with a desktop environment by themselves. You only need to see if your display manager works properly. Depends on which one you are using, there is different answer to your question, but I believe [this page](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/display_managers) can help you to figure out which one works for you.